# Since questions won't necessarily get migrated here, can we copy them?

Tags: discussion

Since questions won't really get migrated here until after the public beta, and since there's not really a migration path, what's the word on copying questions verbatim from the one site to this (after offering the author of that question to reask it here)?

The question that brought this up is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941986/how-to-find-the-actual-space-being-consumed-by-indexes-on-a-table-in-oracle but since we're not migrating ... you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and migrated that one since it was

- unanswered
- a very strong match to this site

It is not unheard of to migrate questions to a site in beta, but *only for exceptional circumstances* ... these seemed suitably exceptional to me.

Comment: thanks. Do we have an MSO tracker on this? Can I just pester Rebecca with questions on stuff like this?

Comment: @drach no idea what you're talking about. Any diamond mod can migrate any question to any site, though there are warnings about beta migrations.

Comment: Then I'll pester her with said questions since she and Robert do community stuff and I cross her path more often than his.

Comment: I should've said instead of `this` : `copying questions of questionable migratability instead of asking for them to be migrated` ... or should we just open meta.dba.se tickets on the ones we think are valid migration candidates? Or just flag 'em with a good message on SO and keep going?